# Laravel Echo PresenceChannel vs listen events doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, echo.js

Good time, for the implementation of the chat room, I have done all the Pusher configurations correctly, and sending messages and displaying online users works correctly, but the event in the .listen method does not work, and it does not even log. Thank you for your help. I have been dealing with this problem for a long time. I hit

[this is my event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVrC8.png)

and in echo.js
[My problem is in the .listen section, where the event is not executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESksn.png)

this is channels.php
[channels.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIQ37.png)

[and this messagecontroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkXwf.png)

Comment: Add the broadcastAs function and set it to something other than the class name. Then your front end just listens for that same string with a full stop in front of it. Example, broadcastAs is “message.sent” and in the front end you listen for “.message.sent”

Comment: I've done exactly that before, but it still didn't work out.